# Yii2 повторное использование кода

Tags: php, yii2

На стороне контроллера получаю данные и отправляю их в виде массивов в вид. В виде из массива начинаю делать карточки товаров. Пытаюсь вынести логику создания карточки в отдельный вид, создать функцию, чтобы можно было

```
$this->layout = false;
return $this->render('page', compact('data'));
```

получить готовый HTML и вставлять его где нужно. Пробовал писать на стороне контроллера статические функции и вызывать из из вида, но так ведь не хорошо. Да и начинается, что статические функции не могут обращаться не к статическим и т.п. Да и в статическом методе не получается `$this->layout = false;` и всё что связано с `$this`.

Словом, как быть? Как можно реализовать?

Comment: А что мешает прямо из вида в нужном месте вызвать `<?= $this->render('card_item') ?>` ?

Comment: @pa3py6aka. Спасибо. Что-то я слишком мудрил... Будете оформлять ответ?

Comment: Оформил ответ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно просто создать отдельный `view` с карточкой товара, и в других вьюхах в любом нужном месте вставлять его: `<?= $this->render('card_item', ['good' => $good]) ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать виджет еще. Если например будет встречаться карточка в разных контролах.

Comment: Лучший ответ всех времен! Автор ответа шарит! Он заслуживает большей репутации!

Comment: А что мешает использовать один и тот же единственный `view` для карточки в разных контроллерах?

Comment: Технически нечего, логически будет файл общий для нескольких контроллеров и валяться в непонятной папке.